# How are normal and separable extensions linked in Galois theory?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am sure this is quite a basic question but I am having trouble understanding whole these key concepts are related

Say we had a field extension $L/K$ .. How do the concepts of being normal and separable relate to our understanding of the Galois group $Gal(L/K)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory

Answer (score 1):

One of the characterizations of being a Galois extension (for a finite extension) is that it is normal and separable.

If you know that your extension is a Galois extension, then all sorts of wondrous things happen such as the order of the Galois group being the degree of the extension and many other nice things.

See here:

[Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory)

[Characterizations of Galois Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension)

Comment: ah ok thanks. Also, when finding the Galois group of a polynomial, does the polynomial have to be normal and separable or is this just for field extensions? Is it true that it must be irreducible and monic?